# Retag questions reputation

Tags: support, tags, reputation, suggested-edits

On [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) is a list of reputation values and the privileges they give. It says:

> 500    Retag questions

But it is possible with fewer reputation points. I have 370 and I can edit the tags of questions.

I think I can do that since I reached 200 (+ bonus) 300 rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *suggest* any edit, but it has to be approved by people with more reputation before it is actually applied.

At 500 reputation, this approval isn't necessary anymore if you just want to edit the tags; at 2000 it's not necessary at all, no matter what you're editing.

Comment: I see. Thanks. May be that should be mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: @smartmeta good point, maybe "Retag questions without peer review" would be less confusing indeed.